# Parsing text that requires lookahead using nom

Tags: parsing, rust

**tl;dr**: I'm struggling to find documentation or examples of text parsers that require lookahead using nom.

**Long version**

I'm using nom to parse 6502 assembly. I'm struggling with creating a parser that can parse the various addressing modes. Any given opcode will have the following format:

`XXX AM`

Where `XXX` is a three-character mnemonic and `AM` is the operand. The operand can take many forms and is referred to as the "addressing mode."  I've defined an enum for the operands, an enum for the addressing modes, and an `OpCode` tuple struct containing these values, which is ultimately the result returned when parsing.

The addressing mode can be omitted completely, in which case the addressing mode is `Implied`, it can have a literal value of `A`, which is the `Accumulator` addressing mode.

Many of the addressing modes refer to memory locations, and it's these addressing modes I'm struggling to parse. In particular, if an addressing mode specifies a single byte in the form of `$00`, it is a `ZeroPage` addressing mode, whereas an operand specifying two bytes in the form of `$0000` is an `Absolute` addressing mode. To complicate the matter, there are indexed variants of these addressing modes in the form of `$00,X`, `$00,Y`, `$0000,X`, etc.

Are there any good examples of existing text parsers that would illustrate the correct way to parse values that all start similarly (`$00...`) but are differentiated by how they end?  The nom documentation is not very comprehensive, and the best example I've found is the INI parser, which isn't doing anything as complex as I'm trying to accomplish. I've also look at the syn source code, but it's using a lot of custom macros and is a pretty complex beast, making it hard to learn from.

Comment: Whilst not using nom ... [the 6502 emulator, assembler and disassembler crate that I wrote](https://github.com/simon-whitehead/rs6502) hand-rolls this. Its probably not the best example of parsing in Rust but it certainly manages to do it (NOTE: I am still in a cleanup stage of this - but now the holidays are over its progressing alot slower!). The assembler folder is where it all takes place - its very explicit and quite nested but might help in _some_ way? Of note - I don't look ahead. I just tokenize it and figure it out as I go. So I'm not sure lookahead is what you're after?

Comment: I guess I'm assuming lookahead is required for what I'm trying to do using nom, or at least the way I'm currently approaching it.  Out of curiosity, is your assembler self contained? I'm really just looking for something simple I can use to create nice and readable unit tests for a NES emulator I'm writing.

Comment: You would have to define "self-contained" for me in this context. Its self-contained in the sense that its all written in Rust. Its... not self-contained in the sense that its not in 1 file - it relies on the types in the `lexer.rs`, `parser.rs`, `token.rs`, `assembler.rs` files ... etc. It should be simple enough for you to include as a dependency and use - I say that without knowing your specific use case though. The assembler is very limited (currently) when parsing 6502 mnemonic code as input. For example, it doesn't have fancy macros or conditional constructs like some assemblers do.

Comment: There are lots of example usages in the crate though - I wrote LOTS of unit tests for every part of that crate - down to individual opcodes. So you should be able to eyeball simple usages of it.

Comment: Self contained in the sense that it's a separate crate. In any event, I'll certainly take a look!

Comment: Well it also contains an emulator ... so technically you could just use the emulator in the crate and have your address bus map the other hardware into the memory mapped in the emulator in my crates' CPU :D Hopefully theres something there that can help you anyway - sorry I can't really help from the nom side of things anyway.

Comment: I've implemented my own emulator and it's functionally correct (at least according to the functional test ROM I test against) and recently reworked it to accommodate cycle-granular timing with other components, as opposed to single-stepping and time warping. The need for the assembler is to write tests that assemble a single instruction, execute it, and assert the correct number of cycles was executed. This is necessary since the number of cycles isn no longer taken from a cycle table, but is actually dependent on the number of reads/writes a particular opcode performs.

Comment: One option is using `alt!()` with the alternatives in the right order - so include the indexed modes before the shorter ones.

Comment: I will give this a try. Thanks for the suggestion, it seems like the obvious solution in hindsight.

Comment: @ChrisEmerson Your suggestion worked--If you want to submit your comment as an answer, I will mark it as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way of doing this is with the `alt!()` macro.

The idea is have a parser which tries each alternative in sequence.  So if you already have parsers for each of the addressing modes separately, you can combine them into a parser for any of them:

```rs
// The sub-parsers all return Operand too.
named!(parse_operand<&str, Operand>,
    alt!(parse_absolute_indexed |
         parse_absolute |
         parse_zeropage_indexed |
         parse_zeropage |
         parse_implied));
```

Some notes:

- The order may be important; I've put `parse_absolute` after `parse_absolute_indexed` since the former would match the initial part of the operand and return too early.
- A variant would be to include the end of line (including comments if applicable) matching into each sub parser.  Then it couldn't match early.
- If you're parsing to the end of the input without a byte/character which terminates the pattern (such as a newline) then you may need to use `alt_complete!()` instead of `alt!()`.  The reason for this is that if you try matching `ADD $00`, the parser which might match `ADD $0000` has to assume that it might still match if more input arrives, and `alt!()` won't then skip to the next case.  Using `alt_complete!()`, or alternatively wrapping the inner matchers in `complete!()`, is saying that an incomplete match is a non-match.

If the parsers were very complicated it might mean doing extra work (trying each parse in sequence) compared to a parser generated by eg the venerable `yacc`, but I don't think it's an issue in this case.

Comment: One thing I should note is that I had to use `alt_complete!` while ordering the parsers correctly as you stated. Without `alt_complete`, parsing would fail on some of the memory addressing modes with `IResult::Incomplete`.

Comment: Thanks; I've added a note.  Let me know if it doesn't seem right!